Redirecting to Private URI from Spring Authorization Server
I'm configuring spring authorization server v3.2.4 and facing issues while redirecting to a private URI (used in mobile platforms and native apps).
I have below configuration in my security config class.
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
            .requestMatchers("/error","/health", "/images/**", "/css/**")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
        )
        .formLogin(form -> form
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                );
    return http.cors(Customizer.withDefaults()).build();
}

I have setup a custom login page and authentication provider to validate the credentials against our user database. Client configuration is also maintained in our database.
I'm using authentication code flow, wherein in the first step, a user is provided with a login page. On successful login, an authentication code is returned. In the second step, on exchange of this code, an access token is generated.
The step 1 works fine when I have a absolute URL configured in Client configuration. E.g. If I configure http://localhost:8080/oauth2redirect as my redirect URL, I receive the response from my server as http://localhost:8080/oauth2redirect?code=<authorization_code>.
However, if I configure a private URI, e.g. com.mycompany.myapp:/oauth2redirect, the response is sent to
http://localhost:9090/oauthcom.mycompany.myapp:/oauth2redirect?code=<authorization_code>, where http://localhost:9090/oauth is my authorization server URL.
On debugging the code, I see that, after successful login, the request reaches a filter OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter's sendAuthorizationResponse() method, where it uses DefaultRedirectStrategy as its redirection strategy class. Here, the private URI is treated a relative URL and eventually gets attached to server's context root. In method calculateRedirectUrl(),
if (!UrlUtils.isAbsoluteUrl(url)) {
  if (isContextRelative()) {
    return url;
  }
  return contextPath + url;
}

I would like to know if someone knows how to use Spring Authorization Server with private URIs.

If you were using Android App Link and iOS Smart Link (instead of using a custom scheme, which is now discouraged for security reasons), you would not have this problem...

Thanks @ch4mp for your reply. Let me ask my app team if they can come up with app links. They just shared the custom URI with me and I am struggling with the issue shared above.
